# Ubuntu not connecting to ethernet nor wireless

Tags: networking, drivers

Just finished a custom build and installed 14.04 LTS. The biggest issue I'm having is I can't connect it to the Internet for the life of me. The Ethernet is directly connected, but not accessing anything on-line. The wireless pci card I installed sees networks, but can never connect to them. I've gone through almost every tutorial on-line I've found with similar issues, but most require either the wireless or at least the Ethernet to work.

It seems to be an issue with the Realtek r8169 driver. I've tried several posts with similar issues, but they don't work (ie downloading current drivers from realtek, cd the folder, make install, etc.)

So what can I possibly do to fix it without any connectivity?

here's my `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port B) (rev 02)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port B)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port D)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port E)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port H)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
02:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. Device 3483 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

Comment: I am tempted to take a guess or two but hesitant until you tell me just a little more about your computer such as the brand, configuration (laptop, desktop), age (years), history (dropped, wet, yard sale).  And if you ever knew the internet to connect to it under another OS (windows, other linux, previous ubuntu).

Comment: CPU: AMD FX 8350 - 4 Ghz, Memory: 8gb RAM, HDD: 128gb SSD, Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-970A-D3P AM, GPU: EVGA GeForce GTX 750 2GB, PCIe: TP-LINK TL-WDN4800 Dual Band Wireless N900...All parts were ordered and brand new. The wireless pci came with windows drivers, so assuming it works fine on windows 8, but I haven't installed that os on this machine

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering my comment in such fine detail.  It looks like a robust system and should work.  I suspect your WiFi connectivity problem is caused by a very common problem I frequently solve with a minimal configuration change.

First remove your WiFi card and you should find that your Ethernet connection works now.  I see this pretty often where there are WiFi setup problems.

Next reinstall your WiFi card and install [WIFI RADAR](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/wifi-radar/) and use it to determine which radio channels your neighbors are using and see if it might be the same as your own WiFi source.  If so, change your source to be the least in conflict with your neighbors.  When you have removed the conflict it should work.

Comment: Got the ethernet working, and updated the system. I installed the wifi radar. Whatever the current driver I have currently has the ability to see and connect to networks, but websites and updates do not work without the ethernet plugged in. Any ideas? I think we're getting close, and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you verified that your WiFi modem is actually serving internet?  I would assume you have a smartphone.  Does it connect to the internet with it?  If so it's something else, but to me it sure sounds like there isn't internet on your WiFi.

Comment: Wifi is definitely working, I have four room mates and they are all connected.

Comment: I think it is not using the ath9k driver correctly, but not sure

Comment: For now I would advise using an alternate WiFi device.  Surely you must already own a USB WiFi adapter.  I have several as they are handy to have around.  Best of all, it is easier to place a USB WiFi adapter at the end of a USB extension cable, than it is to extend the antenna of a fixed WiFi card.